# Three.js / BufferGeometry how to use mesh & line material

Tags: three.js

I'm using BufferGeometry to draw triangles.
I can use a mesh geometry, specifiyng 3 index-attribute for every triangle. I'm using a basic material without wireframe. I suposse I'll can use raycast.

Also I have seen the linesegments approach for wireframe. Interesting.

Ok, my problem... I'd like to see my triangles as a wireframe and also I need raycast. So .... the solution is to create my own shader, isn't it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to create a custom shader you can have a mesh with wireframe material, and the ray should still "hit" the object

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe : true}));
```

if it for some reason does not hit or you want to LineSegments object you can keep track of all transformations that affected the object, and apply them onto a mesh you wont add to scene

```
var segmentObject = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry,lineMaterial);
scene.add(segmentObject);
var meshNotInScene = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,dummyMaterial);
```

and you will use the mesh object to determine if raycast hit the object

this way you can have a different hitbox for an object for example if you have a flying donut by pairing it with a circle mesh you can select it even if you click in its hole etc...

keep in mind that materials have sides and if you dont care about which side is which set "side" to THREE.DoubleSide

Comment: BufferGeometry has nothing to do with material, if you create mesh with buffer geometry and wireframe material it will create a wireframe, i tested it just to be sure with a simple PlaneBufferGeometry and simple material, and it did show up as a wireframe, so your problem must be somewhere else